# Do the mimics of the Grin Reaper Mask do any damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I recently got my hands on one of these from Kedala. Here is the link to the mask: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-grin-reaper

It's a cool mask. But does the mimics actually do any damage at all?

Firebats seem to proc them pretty often so they are always there, but what is their own proc rate of casting a spell? I've seen them cast Firebats, Zombie bears. But their proc rate of casting spell seems variable, they seem to cast Firebats all the time, but cast Zombie Bears once in a while, Grasp of the Dead very very rarely and never cast Piranha.

Which spells benefit most from these mimics, could anyone knowledgeable shed some light into it?

Another question; right now I'm using Firebats as my main damage spell. I've got 13% Firebats damage rolled on the mask, is getting a 6% CHC worth more than this one DPS wise?

Comment: Regarding the firebats vs CHC, are you using firebats for the damage or is this a Fetish Sycophants build?

Comment: It is impossible to compare skill damage bonus to CHC without knowing CHD, other Firebats damage bonuses and usage ratio of Firebats to your other skills.

Answer (score 1):

This post here provides a lot of information regarding Grin Reaper and how to build around the mask.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3witchdoctors/comments/2ba2rn

A couple of things of interest:

- Mimics do around 80% of your overall damage
- They cast spells that you currently have on your skill bar, minus things like Fetish Army, Spirit Walk, Wall of Zombies, Hex, Pet cooldowns, and Sacrifice.

Currently, the best spell for the Mimics to cast is actually Corpse Spider - Spider Queen, due to the fact that Mimics do not have a limit on the number of spider queen that they can spawn (whereas you can only spawn one at a time).  This allows you to field an army of spider queens, which is quite powerful.

In regards to your second question, in general, CHC will give you a bigger damage boost, up to a point. Usually the rule is to keep a 1:10 ratio between CHC:CHD.  If you are low on CHC, then the 6% will be useful.  However, if you already have high CHC (~49%), then having more Firebat damage (if that is your primary skill), could be a better trade off.  This really depends on the type of build that you are trying to achieve.  Pets builds will benefit more from having higher CHC.

Comment: Could you confirm if they randomly cast spells you have equipped, or do they "mimic" the player if they cast an ability they support?